# Excel Auto-Number Urls

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make an excel formula to auto number urls.

Right now I have two columns, one column with the max number and one column with the base url.

There are 1050 rows.

Basically, I want to generate for each row a total number of columns between 0 and the max number. In these columns I want the url appended with the current column no.

Example:

Max number = 10, url = thing.com/

This would result in thing.com/0 | thing.com/1 | thing.com/2 and so on.

Any way I can do this?

Comment: It isn't terribly clear what results you are hoping to achieve but perhaps `="thing.com/"&MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 10)` filled down.

Comment: @Jeeped Right now I have something like this: http://prntscr.com/amroep
For A1-B1 i want to fill 59 columns (0-58) after B1 with the current column number appended to the end of the url. So for C1 it'd be test.com/1, then for D1 it'd be test.com/2.  I want to automate this for each row so it auto fills the columns to match this.  Sorry if my explanation sucks, and sorry that I'm not too good at Excel.

Answer (score 0):

please use the below function as formula in any cells with the Selection of ranges.

```
Public Function getcontent(r As Range) As String
    Dim out As String
    For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count
        If out <> "" Then out = out & "|thing.com/" & r.Cells(i, 1) Else out = "thing.com/" & r.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
    getcontent = out
End Function
```

[image]